# Configure docker Wordpress using Nginx ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I have a docker with Nginx that listen to the port 3500 with ssl, then I have a docker with Wordpress installed that listens in port 3400:80

In the nginx.conf I have this:

```
http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;

      root /var/www/html;

      index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


      location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }

    }


 server {
          listen 3500 ssl;
          server_name test.com;

          ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/cert.pem;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;


          location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.226:3400;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
          }
        }
```

And in the wp-config.php I have this:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

define('WP_HOME','https://test.com:3500');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://test.com:3500');

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

But when I access to https://test.com:3500 I get the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Could you tell me the correct way so I don't have this infinite loop redirection please?